# mysql.connector.errors.InternalError: Unread result found error while using "DELETE"

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, mysql-connector, mysql-connector-python

I'm currently learning python connectivity with `MySQL` , these are the lines for making tables

```
    import mysql.connector
    mydb=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="root")
    #CREATING DATABASE AND TABLE
    mycursor=mydb.cursor()
    mycursor.execute("create database if not exists store")
    mycursor.execute("use store")
    mycursor.execute("create table if not exists signup(username varchar(20),password varchar(20))")
    mycursor.execute("create table if not exists buynewbooks(nameofbook varchar(30))")
    mycursor.execute("create table if not exists feedback(rating varchar(11))")
```

And here is the code block from which I am getting error:

```
    #delete acc 
        elif  ch==3:
                mycursor.execute("select username from signup")
                u=str(input("enter your registerd USERNAME"))   
                p=str(input("enter your account password"))
                sql = "DELETE FROM signup WHERE username = u AND password = p" 
                mycursor.execute(sql)
                mydb.commit
                print("your account has been removed")
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/win10/.spyder-py3/kj7.py", line 34, in <module>
mycursor.execute(sql)
File "C:\Users\win10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 547, in execute
self._connection.handle_unread_result()
File "C:\Users\win10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 1286, in handle_unread_result
raise errors.InternalError("Unread result found")
mysql.connector.errors.InternalError: Unread result found
```

Please tell if I should give any more part of code.

Comment: You miss params in `execute` most likely. Also that used `sql` string should have `%s` instead of `u` and `p`. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html.

Comment: Apart of that it may be because of `mycursor.execute("select username from signup")` which was not fetched. Please comment this line and see what happens.

Comment: For SQL statements that have a result set is expected that a `cursor.fetchall()`, `cursor.fetchone()` or `cursor.fetchmany()` to be called. This change was introduced in the last release to comply with Python DB API:


"An Error (or subclass) exception is raised if the previous call to .execute*() did not produce any result set or no call was issued yet."